# Is there "implicit" allocation of arrays in c++ by declaration?

Tags: c++, arrays, allocation, variable-length-array

I would like to allocate memory for arrays, when their sizes are not known until run time, in C++.

I often use constant (compile-time) allocation; but would like to make progress towards "always" using run-time allocation. I actually got away with "implicit" allocation by declaration. (My terminology for what happened.) And I wonder what it is really called, and why it works. A snippet that I think tells the tale:

```
std::ifstream infile;
infile.open("input_info");
if (infile.is_open()) {
  infile >> number;
  std::cout << number << "  " << std::endl;
}

std::pair<int, int> incident_subdomains[number]; 
int sd[number][2];
```

That is; after reading in the desired arrays' size, I declare arrays incident_subdomains and sd. I then use these arrays in subsequent code; e.g., to read in information from "input_info" to fill the arrays. The program compiled and ran. Is this a new feature of C++? I like it. (I have used "new", and "vector".) The c++ compiler I am using is g++ 7.3.0.

Comment: This is a vendor extension. Your code is not valid standard C++.

Comment: Variable Length Arrays are a C feature that some C++ compilers support as a non-standard extension. Don't use them in C++. Use `std::vector`.

Comment: What you try to do is a [*variable-length array*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), and C++ doesn't have those. Use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why do you see it as progress? Why do you not want to use `std::vector`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And I wonder what it is really called

Variable length array.

> Is this a new feature of C++?

No. This is not a feature in *standard* C++. In C++, the size of a non-dynamically allocated array must be compile time constant.

> and why it works

Presumably, because it is a language extension provided by your compiler. It is a feature in C99 (and optionally in C11), so some C++ compilers that are also C99 compliant (it is quite common for C++ compiler to also be C compilers) are likely to have such feature. This is what GCC says about your program:

> ```
> warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'incident_subdomains' [-Wvla]
> ```

While Clang says:

> ```
>  warning: variable length arrays are a C99 feature [-Wvla-extension]
> ```

The simplest way to create a dynamically sized array in standard C++ is to use `std::vector`.

Comment: Both GCC and Clang only say that with the `-pedantic` flag set though. (One should probably always set that one.)

Comment: @user10605163 You also get the warning or if you set the warning option explicitly. This means that unless you use `-pedantic`, both compilers fail to conform to the standard  which requires in this case that there be a diagnostic message.

Comment: @eerorika - depends on how you look at it. All the standards require for a diagnosable error is emitting a message (the diagnostic). Nothing is said about suppressing a diagnostic (e.g. configuring the compiler to not emit a specified set of diagnostics by default) or providing an option to activate it (e.g. command line options).   Bear in mind that compiler vendors often suppress diagnostics in response to lobbying by programmers (e.g. programmers demand capability to suppress warnings, in cases where the compiler can still output object or executable code).

Comment: @Peter It sure can be useful occasionally to ask the compiler to violate the standard a bit and it's not bad for the compiler to support that. It's just a bit unfortunate that both of these popular compilers violate the standard by default. Even more unfortunate that the violation remains when standard is explicitly specified using `-std=c++XX`.

Comment: @eerorika -  Maybe so.   But early lobbying by programmers gave compiler vendors a loud and clear message that it was better to suppress any messages by default, unless they indicated problems that would cause a build to fail.   You'll be hard pressed to find any compiler that does things differently.  There are still too many real-world programmers who think the same way, so this is unlikely to change any time soon.  Hence the need to use additional compilation options for those folks who want the diagnostics.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the informative answers. I do use "vector"; except for one variable. Though I could set up and use a vector of pairs, I did not (figure out how to) pass relevant pointers into a function. So, I used "new", which works fine.

I cannot imagine not using run time allocations of my main (mesh-relevant) arrays. 
I went through several version of the code.

In one, I tried to use "implicit" allocation - just declaring an array size at run time; though that is clearly not standard, as you all point out. Having it work was a surprise.

BTW: I would see that as progress, because it is easier. But I try to follow the standard.

Tim